# Как сохранить страницу в html?

Tags: php, html

Нужно чтобы после выполнения скрипта PHP html страница(которая сформирована с помощью PHP), сохранялась в файле. Подскажите как?(решения,которые нашел в гугле не работают*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    // Включает буферизацию вывода
    ob_start();
?>

<body>
    test
</body>

<?php
    // Получает содержимое текущего буфера и удаляет его
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    // Запишет данные в файл
    file_put_contents('test.php', $html);
    // Если еще надо вернуть эту страницу в браузер
    echo $html
?>
```